# Is there a way to create a dataframe from a dictionary with list of values?

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary `myDict` and I'd like to create a dataframe `df` using this `myDict` as follows:

```
myDict = {
1: [''],
2: ['07/19/2017', ' 10/18/2007', '12/20/2002','12/20/2002' ],
3: ['07/19/2017', ' 10/18/2007'],
4: ['12/13/1993'],
5: [''],
6: ['08/01/2007'],
7: ['04/23/2007'],
8: ['02/06/2007'],
9: ['02/06/2007'],
10: ['11/08/2001'],
11: [''],
12: [''],
13: ['12/20/2002']
}

df
ID    Col1         Col2          Col3         Col4
1     
2     07/19/2017   10/18/2007    12/20/2002   12/20/2002 
3     07/19/2017   10/18/2007 
4     12/13/1993   
5     
6     08/01/2007
7     04/23/2007
8     02/06/2007
9     02/06/2007
10    11/08/2001
11    
12    
13    12/20/2002
```

How do I make this possible? Thank you.

Putting everything into a function isn't working...

```
def split_Date(df):
    Dates1 = df.set_index('IDX')['Date'].to_dict()
    dates = {}
    for k, v in Dates1.items():
       v = v.split(',')
       dates[k] = [i for i in v]
    dates = {k: sorted(v, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.strip(), "%m/%d/%Y") if x != "" else x) for k, v in dates.items()}
    df_dates = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dates, orient="index").fillna('').rename_axis("IDX").rename(columns="Date{}".format).reset_index()
    df = pd.merge(df, df_dates, on='IDX', how='inner', suffixes=('_chem', '_df'))
    return df #Adding this doesn't make any difference
```

Running this code outside a function works perfectly. However, this requires me to change the value of `myData` in all the lines for everytime I have a new `data`. This isn't as productive as having a function

```
Dates1 = myData.set_index('IDX')['Date'].to_dict()
dates = {}
for k, v in Dates1.items():
    v = v.split(',')
    dates[k] = [i for i in v]
dates = {k: sorted(v, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.strip(), "%m/%d/%Y") 
if x != "" else x) for k, v in dates.items()}
df_dates = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dates, orient="index").fillna('').rename_axis("IDX").rename(columns="Date{}".format).reset_index()
myData = pd.merge(myData, df_dates, on='IDX', how='inner', suffixes=('_chem', '_df'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read it in using *pd.DataFrame.from_dict* and set the key as index via *orient* parameter:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(myDict, orient="index").fillna('')

#            0           1           2           3
#1              
#2  07/19/2017  10/18/2007  12/20/2002  12/20/2002
#3  07/19/2017  10/18/2007      
#4  12/13/1993          
#5              
#6  08/01/2007          
# ...
```

---

To set the keys as a separate column, you can use [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(myDict, orient="index")
 .fillna('')
 .rename_axis("ID")
 .rename(columns="Col{}".format)
 .reset_index())

#  ID         Col0        Col1        Col2        Col3
#0  1               
#1  2   07/19/2017  10/18/2007  12/20/2002  12/20/2002
#2  3   07/19/2017  10/18/2007      
#3  4   12/13/1993          
#4  5
# ...
```

Comment: thank you. I do want to retain the `ID` as a column (not just as the df index) because I need it to merge this `df` to other dataframes when needed. How do I get this done?

Comment: You can use `reset_index` to convert the index to an actual column. Added some methods to rename column names as well; you might use it as you need.

Comment: Thank you. My last question (I promise :D) would be, can the list of dates be sorted so the earliest date fills the first column? i.e. for `#2` `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` and `Col4` would be: `12/20/2002`, `12/20/2002`,  `10/18/2007` and `07/19/2017`

Comment: You can pre sort your dictionary's values with something like this. `from datetime import datetime;
new_dict = {k: sorted(v, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.strip(), "%m/%d/%Y") if x != "" else x) for k, v in myDict.items()};` Then use this new dictionary to construct the data frame using above method. `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict, orient="index")`

Comment: I have the code all in a function but it isn't working at all. I'm wondering if you could give it a look for me. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? You are not returning `df` at the end of the function btw.

Comment: Exactly! Especially since running the code outside a function works perfectly. It just doesn't make sense to me. The code I just added works by itself but having it in a function (even when `df` is returned, doesn't.